# Ant Script call 2 batch file one after another

Tags: batch-file, ant

I want to call 2 batch file one after another through ANT. First batch file is a "Server". Second batch file is a "runner". "Runner" is completely based on "Server" batch file.

Problem is both batch files started parellally. So second batch file got failed. because first file took almost 2 mins to startup completely. I want to call second(Runner) batch once first(Server) started successfully.

Below is the script:

```
<target name="start1">
<exec dir="C:\sonar-3.7.4\bin\windows-x86-64" executable="cmd" os="Windows 7">
             <arg line="/c start StartSonar.bat"/> 
</exec>

</target>

<target name="start2" depends="start1">
<exec dir="C:\sonar-runner-2.4\bin" executable="cmd" os="Windows 7">
         <arg line="/c start sonar-runner.bat"/>
</exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the keyword `start` from

```
  <arg line="/c start StartSonar.bat"/>
```

Comment: It is not working when i remove "start". Just waiting. Second target not yet called.